# Chrome complaining "restaurant_name" is not defined, but in the page it actually display the value

Tags: angular

Here is the error message in the developer's console

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'restaurant_name' of
>   undefined
>           at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (RestaurantDetailComponent.html:2)
>           at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.es5.js:13094)
>           at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12241)
>           at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12601)
>           at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12533)
>           at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12242)
>           at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12601)
>           at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.es5.js:12559)
>           at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12237)
>           at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12601)
>           ...

But in my details page, the value in `restaurant_name` is actually displayed.

Here is the code for detail page implementation:
file: restaurant-detail.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Restaurant } from '../restaurant';
import { RestaurantService } from '../restaurant.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-restaurant-detail',
  templateUrl: './restaurant-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./restaurant-detail.component.css']
})
export class RestaurantDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  id: Number;
  sub: any;
  @Input() restaurant: Restaurant;
  constructor(private restaurantService: RestaurantService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
    });
    this.restaurantService.getRestaurant(this.id).then(
      res => this.restaurant = new Restaurant(res.id, res.restaurant_name, res.description
      , res.phone, res.address, res.category));
  }

}
```

file: restaurant-detail.component.html

```
Restaurant detail page with Id: {{ id }}
<section>
   Name: {{ restaurant['restaurant_name'] }}
</section>
```

file: restaurant-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { Restaurant } from './restaurant';
@Injectable()
export class RestaurantService {
  private restaurantUrl = 'api/restaurant'; // URL to web API
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  //Get all restaurants
  getRestaurants(): Promise<Restaurant[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.restaurantUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json().
        map(x => new Restaurant(x.id, x.restaurant_name, x.description, x.phone, x.address,
          x.category)))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getRestaurant(id: Number):Promise<Restaurant>{
    return this.http.get(this.restaurantUrl + "/" + id)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json());
  }
  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('Error', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

I using spring boot as my backend to retrieve the data. Currently it seems working, but I want to know why I got this error and how to resolve it, thanks.

Full Github code: https://github.com/zhengye1/Eatr/tree/dev

Comment: This should do it - `Name: {{ restaurant?.restaurant_name }}`

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the restaurant-detail.component.html as below with an `*ngIf`

```
<section *ngIf="restaurant">
   Name: {{ restaurant['restaurant_name'] }}
</section>
```

The reason it prints as such in the console because the restaurant is probably not defined. Adding an `*ngIf` only renders the view after a value is assigned to restaurant variable.

Extra:
Until that data is assigned or loaded, you can add a loader.
If you're using angular 4 have a look at [*ngIf else as well](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#showing-an-alternative-template-using-else).
Or else, you can write your own else as well.

Comment: Seems working. But why the way I did, Chrome will complain?

Comment: @VincentZheng It is because when the template is rendered before the data for the variable/input restaurant is assigned after the service/server-call. Until then it's undefined. So the error pops up when the browser has to show the value of an undefined variable at the moment. Did this help you to understand or need more help?

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining cause with initial render this value is undefined and only shows after request.

To fix it set initial value of restaurant.

```
@Input() restaurant: Restaurant = {};
```

But you are not passing restarurant so you can just write without input

```
restaurant: Restaurant = {}; or new Restarurant depends on object.
```

Or the last one just use ? in template that will tell angular that this value can be undefined.

```
   Name: {{ restaurant?.restaurant_name }}
```